# How to give user permissions to edit other user fields except user id & pwd?

Tags: users

Hi i am using drupal 7 website in my site having 3 different role of users 1st role of users need to edit 2nd role of user fields  except user id & pwd & email & roles.i have tried with administer user permissions,it is possible to edit user id and pwd.Also i have tried with user protect module no use,Any suggestions on this it will be very helpful.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is [Restrict Password Change](https://www.drupal.org/project/restrict_password_change) module.

**Related modules:**

- https://www.drupal.org/project/user_readonly
- https://www.drupal.org/project/userprotect

Comment: @ Gulok - Thanks for your response,I will check with this and get back to you.

Comment: for pwd i will check with this..how we can hide user id and email,roles of others is it possible with this module.

Comment: For that my first solution I have in my mind is to implement `hook_form_alter` with respect to user roles and hide the fields that you want.

Comment: @  Gulok - thanks for you suggestions..its working:)

Comment: Glad that it works.